# Datatable row.child.isShow() function undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I'm using `DataTable()` where i need to create a row child.
But I'm when i use row.child it shows row ,child is undefined.

here is the code

```
$('.btn-showintern').click(function () {
    debugger;
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var table = $('#travelRequest').DataTable();
    var row1 = table.rows(tr);
    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {

        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }
   else {
       Open this row
       row1.child(InternalTravel()).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
```

But is throwing error like row.child is undefined.
i went through this link also [jQuery DataTables - Child Rows and "Undefined is Not a Function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107586/jquery-datatables-child-rows-and-undefined-is-not-a-function)
please help me on this

Comment: Can you please create a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Please update your code as given below -

```
$('.btn-showintern').click(function () {
var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
var table = $('#travelRequest').DataTable();
var row1 = table.rows(tr);
if ( row1.child.isShown() ) {
    row1.child.hide();
    tr.removeClass('shown');
}
```